# AWS CDK deploy: require argument if there is more than a single stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

My env Typescript, node.js, cdk. I try to deploy AWS stack that consists of two stacks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";

import { WafRegionalStack } from '../lib/WafRegionalStack'
import { ReactStack } from '../lib/ReactStack';


const app = new cdk.App();

new WafRegionalStack(app, 'WafRegionalStack', {})

new ReactStack(app, 'ReactStack', {})
```

I use a command:

```
npx deploy
```

Doing this deployment process get a mistake

```
require argument if there is more than a single stack
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html under Specify Stacks is how you can deploy specific or all stacks at once.

specifically

```
cdk deploy StackName
```

or with wildcards

```
cdk deploy Stack\*
```

in your specific situation, you can use:

```
cdk deploy WAF\* React\*
```

or

```
cdk deploy --all
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than a single stack in the app we need to choose the CLI command:

```
npx cdk deploy '*'
```